# Sencha Touch filter dataview store and refresh list

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch

Seems easy enough but after hours and hours of wasted time I must ask.

I have a nested dataview list with a store that gets populated from an api. Each record is neat and and easy to parse. Like this:

```
 title: 'some title'
 starred: false       // some are "starred: true" and thats what I want
 state: 1
 statetyped: 1
```

I simply need to tap a button that says "starred" and filter the list to show just the starred items.

I have tried everything under the sun, including:

```
    sto.filterBy(function(record){
        var title = record.get('starred');
        if(title == "true" || title == true)
            return record;
    });

    //doesnt work 

    sto.filter(function (record) {
        if (record.data.starred == true) {
            return record;
        }
    });

    //same, doesn't work
```

I even got desperate and filtered the list with underscore.js, created a new store and tried to load the new store, but to no avail.

---

**The console error is:**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'detach' of null* (Default.js?_dc=1392147674804:140)

If it helps:

my dataview view: http://jsfiddle.net/8ycnR/
list controller:  http://jsfiddle.net/a7ZaX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have in your model `starred` field type configured as `bool` you can simply use `Ext.data.Store` [`filter()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method.

As first parameter you should pass property name and as second parameter value to filter by:

```
sto.filter('starred', true);
```

Comment: I do have have the bool set in my model: http://jsfiddle.net/9JTFS/ ..  Still getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'detach' of null"  happening in 'src/layout/Default.js'

Comment: Hard to say what cause this error but it should not been caused directly by filtering the store. It can be caused by something you do after the store is filtered and dataview refreshed.

Comment: OK You are definitely correct about the 'refresh'.  I completely deleted my 'refresh' function in the dataview and it works as expected!  Now the problem is I cant get my top docked dataview (a horizontal list of buttons) to render without losing it to the 'refresh' issue.   Any idea on a better way to render a another dataview to the same dataview (see my fiddle above)

Comment: You should not render `dataview` into another `dataview`. You can use `container` with `vbox` layout to divide screen into more vertical parts and add into it your two dataviews http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.VBox

Comment: Interesting - I have tried that approach, however the dataview items become not clickable. Also I lose the magic (undocumented) config option of "scrollDock: true", which allows the docked panels that sit on top of the dataview to scroll up.  Thanks though!

Comment: Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dw98mnw8u3b568/Screenshot%202014-02-13%2014.07.10.png